# How to translate module with i18n

Tags: magento2, module, localisation, i18n

I met a problem that how to translate the module's phrase into other languages(eg. Japanese).

**For example, some code may like this:**

> app/code/My_vendor/My_module/Controller/i18n/jp_JP.csv

```
"test","Japanese character"
```

> app/code/My_vendor/My_module/Controller/index.php

```
......
$form = '<h3>test</h3>';
$this->getResponse()->setBody($form);
......
```

If `STORES->Configuration->Locale` Options is selected with English(United States), it will show "test" to users; if Japanese(Japan) is selected, it will show "Japanese character".

I had seen the tutorial　
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html
but I'm not sure what should I do next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 points: You placed translate file into wrong place. The correct path should be `app/code/<My_vendor>/<My_module>/i18n/jp_JP.csv`.

And you didn't use `__('text to translate')` to parse the text to translate in template file.

So in your case, change `$form = '<h3>test</h3>';` to `$form = '<h3>' . __('test') . '</h3>';`

Answer (score 8):

Translation file path should be

> app/code/My_vendor/My_module/i18n/jp_JP.csv

You should write a translate text code in your controller

> `app/code/<My_vendor>/<My_module>/Controller/index.php`

like below

```
$form = '<h3>' . __('test') . '</h3>';
```