# Translation of a module

Tags: magento2, module, translate, i18n

How can I translate an extension (module) ? I tried to create the i18n folder and create the it_IT.csv file. But it does not work, how can I do translation?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/202437/51548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create .csv file depending on your locale selected for stores.
Then In your custom module you can need to follow below standard for translation.

**In php or phtml files:** 
echo __("String which needs to translate")

**In knockout template:**

<span data-bind="i18n: 'String which needs to translate'"></span>